# How does jvm optimize loop code?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, optimization, jvm

There is a method that can search substring from a text(use brute force algorithm, please ignore null pointer)

```
public static int forceSearch(String text, String pattern) {
    int patternLength = pattern.length();
    int textLength = text.length();

    for (int i = 0, n = textLength - patternLength; i <= n; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        for (; j < patternLength && text.charAt(i + j) == pattern.charAt(j); j++) {
            ;
        }
        if (j == patternLength) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Strangely! Use the same algorithm, but the following code is more faster!!!

```
public static int forceSearch(String text, String pattern) {
    int patternLength = pattern.length();
    int textLength = text.length();

    char first = pattern.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0, n = textLength - patternLength; i <= n; i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) != first) {
            while (++i <= n && text.charAt(i) != first)
                ;
        }

        int j = 0;
        for (; j < patternLength && text.charAt(i + j) == pattern.charAt(j); j++) {
            ;
        }
        if (j == patternLength) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I found the second code is obviously faster than first if I run it by jvm. Howere, when I write it in c and run, the two functions take almost the same time. So I think the reason is that jvm optimize loop code

```
if (text.charAt(i) != first) {
    while (++i <= max && text.charAt(i) != first)
        ;
}
```

Am I right? If I'm right, how should we use the jvm optimization strategy to
 optimize our code?

Hope somebody help, thankyou:)

Comment: First place to start is compiling your code, then de-compiling it to view what the compiler produced. When I did that with code in your post, I noticed static optimizations made by the compiler. From there, you'll probably have a more precise question about particular optimizations.

Comment: JVM optimizes the first loop, the second loop, and basically the whole method. But JIT compiler is not always as good as static C compiler. You've manually made an optimization which HotSpot JIT is not capable of, so there is nothing strange here.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I decompile the class file and find it doesn't make much different. I think JIT optimizes the loop just as apangin said.

Comment: @Sam compiler optimizations are but one side. JIT does a lot more.

Comment: Interestingly, the faster version in fact does *more* comparisons than the slower one. And when artificially creating "worst case" tests (where the patterns only appear at the *end* of the input strings), the performance becomes equal. Until now, I'd say that the performance difference is due to caching.When you say that in C, the performance is equal, it would be **very** interesting to see your implementations (and maybe the C compiler versions). Then people could create the disassembly and see what kind of optimizations the C compiler is doing there.

Comment: @Marco13 The C code is very similar to java code. I use devcpp to test. I found the second version is a little slower than the first. So I don't think is due to caching.

Comment: So there seems to be a difference in the optimization that causes the C versions to be equally fast, but the Java versions to show a considerable performance difference (I tried this out). So if I understood this correctly, then the main question is: Why is there such a large difference between both Java versions? (I'll investigate this further tomorrow, it's already 4:15am here, but indeed an interesting question)

Comment: I tried to analyze it further (and intended write an answer with some more technical detail, e.g. the C version and some assembly from both the C- and the Java version). But in my first test, for the C(++) version, the second approach was also *significantly* faster. Maybe I did it wrong. I used `std::string`, for example. If your (plain) C version uses `char*`, then this *might* cause a difference (although I doubt that the ratio between both would differ much...)

Comment: @Marco13 I use char* to take a test. I also want to check assembly to analyze it. But I don't understant assembly. So this question can only be solved in the future. If you have a progress, please tell me. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get to the bottom of this, you'll probably need to instruct the JVM to print the assembly. In my experience, minor tweaks to loops can cause surprising performance differences. But it's not necessarily due to optimizations of the loop itself.

There are plenty of factors that can affect how your code gets JIT compiled. 
For example, tweaking the size of a method can affect your inlining tree, which could mean better or worse performance depending on what your call stack looks like. If a method gets inlined further up the call stack, it could prevent nested call sites from being inlined into the same frame.  If those nested call sites are especially 'hot', the added call overhead could be substantial.  I'm not saying that's the cause here; I'm merely pointing out that there are many thresholds that govern how the JIT arranges your code, and the reasons for performance differences are not always obvious.

One nice thing about using JMH for benchmarks is that you can reduce the influence of such changes by explicitly setting inlining boundaries.  But you can use `-XX:CompileCommand` to achieve the same effects manually.

There are, of course, other factors like cache friendliness that require more intuitive analysis.  Given that your benchmark *probably* doesn't have a particularly deep call tree, I'm inclined to lean towards cache behavior as a more likely explanation.  I would guess that your second version performs better because your comparand (the first chunk of `pattern`) is usually in your L1 cache, while your first version causes more cache churn.  If your inputs are long (and it sounds like they are), then this is a likely explanation.  If not, the reasons could be more subtle, e.g., your first version could be 'tricking' the CPU into employing more aggressive cache prefetching, but in a way that actually *hurts* performance (at least for the inputs you are benchmarking).  Regardless, if cache behavior is to explain, then I wonder why you do not see a similar difference in the C versions.  What optimization flags are you compiling the C version with?

Dead code elimination might also be a factor.  I would have to see what your inputs are, but it's possible that your hand-optimized version causes certain instruction blocks to never be hit during the instrumented interpretation phase, leading the JIT to exclude them from the final assembly.

I reiterate: if you want to get to the bottom of this, you'll want to force the JIT to dump the assembly for each version (and compare to the C versions as well).

Answer (score 1):

This if statement simplify a lot of work (especially when the pattern is found at the end of the input string.

```
   if (text.charAt(i) != first) {
        while (++i <= n && text.charAt(i) != first)
            ;
    }
```

In the first version,  you have to check `j < patternLength` for every i before comparing the first character.

In the second version you don't need to.

But strangely I think for small input it does not make much different.

Could you share the length of items you used to benchmark?

Comment: The input text is a random string only consits of digits and letters(length is 100000). And the input pattern is a substring of text(length is 5000). I test it in 20000 times.

Comment: In my computer(use java 8), the first version costs 2070ms, and the second cost 644ms.

Comment: But when I write it in C, the two version cost the same time.

Comment: Do you run the code independently or you run both version inside the main method?

Comment: run both in a function

Comment: Hence the second version use cache from the first version. Try to run each version independently (one at a time). I am pretty sure they will be same

Comment: I tried them out (not using JMH or so, but) following some "best practices for (simple) Java mircobenchmarks", and the difference is significant, and **not** only due to the order in which the tests are executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for JVM compiler optimization on the internet, the

> "loop unwinding" or "loop unrolling"

should jump out. Again benchmarking is tricky. You will find plenty of SO answer for the same.

Comment: Can you explain more detail according to this case? Thank you!

Comment: @sam If you want to know what different compiler optimizations are then take a look at this notes http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4120/2013fa/lectures/lec25-fa13.pdf. Now on Java it will be more work because JIT will/can further rewrite and optimize the .class byte codes. If you intend to spend more time take a look at oracle jvm flags: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1-2266278.html.

Comment: This does not explain the difference between both Java versions, and even less the difference between Java and C.